# How to change the value of cell in a csv file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

i want to change the value of f3 cell before the echo statement in while loop

```
Exec &> output.csv  

file = "d:/aa.csv"  

while ifs =','  

read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8  

do  

echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8"  

done < $file
```

Comment: What is `ifs`? Did you mean to write `IFS`?

Comment: Odd that you're asking this.  Can't you put in the desired value instead of echoing f3?

Comment: Not only ifs, spaces around the assignment operator would also cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the value, then change it. Correcting errors:

```
while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8  
do  
    f3="something else"
    echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,$f6,$f7,$f8"  
done < "$file" > output.csv
```

or

```
IFS=,
while read -ra fields; do  
    fields[2]="something else"
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done < "$file" > output.csv
```

Comment: in your original csv, each column value may be in double quotation "" format. In that case, you can update your f3 with the double quotation "" too. f3="\"something else\""

Answer (score 1):

To change `f3` to `A3` in your csv use this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/^(([^,]+,){2})[^,]+(.+)$/\1A3\3/' aa.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$3="Whatever"}1' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/[^,]+/REPLACEMENT/3' file.csv
```

This changes the third occurence of non-commas to `REPLACEMENT`.